# Passing data model with LINQ query - enumeration yielded no results with result.ToList()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm not getting any model data passed through to view. I've put a breakpoint on return View(blogResult.ToList()) and the Results View says `Enumeration yielded no results`
Note: bp is getting blogID value passed in correctly.
Is there any reason why nothing is getting passed?

[image]

```
        public IActionResult Display(int bp)
        {
            
          

            var blogResult = from a in _db.Users
                             join b in _db.blog on a.Id equals b.userID where b.blogID == bp
                             join c in _db.comment on b.blogID equals c.blogID
                             select new BlogViewModel {
                                 blogID = b.blogID,
                                 blogTitle = b.blogTitle,
                                 blogContent = b.blogContent,
                                 userID = a.Id, 
                                 publishedDate = b.publishedDate,
                                 firstName = a.firstName,
                                 lastName = a.lastName,
                                 Comments = new CommentModel { comment = c.comment, commentID = c.commentID, reply = c.reply, blogID = b.blogID, userID = a.Id }
                                 };
                                

            return View(blogResult.ToList());
        }
    }
```

Section of view

```
@model IEnumerable<AVI_IT.ViewModels.BlogViewModel>

<div class="container">

    @foreach (var v in Model)
    {
        <h1 class="blogTitle">@v.blogTitle</h1>
        <p id="blogAuthor">@v.firstName | @v.publishedDate</p>
        <img src="~/images/slider-img3.png" id="blogImage" />
        <p id="blogContent">
            @v.blogContent
        </p>

    }
```

Comment: Are you sure there's an entry in `blog` with the given `blogID` and if so does it have any related values in `comment` since you're using inner joins.  FYI if you have Navigation Properties I'd suggest using those instead of Joins.

Comment: The data Context is probably empty (_db).  You must initially query the database to fill the Data Context when the application starts.

Comment: yes there is a blogID (102 for example) with data populated in record

Answer (score 0):

The implictly typed query returns an anonymous type, so to bind the result to a list you can try casting to the type explicitly like this:

```
return View(blogResult.ToList<BlogViewModel>());
```

Or try iterating and appending to the type as shown:

```
List<BlogViewModel> lst = new List<BlogViewModel>();

foreach (var item in blogResult)
{
    lst.Add(item);
}

return View(lst);
```

If the query doesn't return any results then (like the previous comments suggested) check the data in the individual tables, OR with my second suggestion, verify that each item in the anonymous list can be added to the list and casted to the BlogViewModel DTO (e.g. there may be a field that is required or has a restriction).